# Erro ao adidicionar a Controler em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, scaffold

Bom dia, estou fazendo uma pequena solução utilizando ASP.NET MVC com Entity Framework 6 para atender a um trabalho do meu curso. Crei a classe de contexto:

```
namespace WillianRibeiro.EstudandoMVC.Web.Data{
public class EstudandoMVCContext : DbContext
{
    public EstudandoMVCContext()
        :base("EstudandoMVC_Desenv")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
 }  }
```

Criei a Model:

```
namespace WillianRibeiro.EstudandoMVC.Web.Data{
public class EstudandoMVCContext : DbContext
{
    public EstudandoMVCContext()
        :base("EstudandoMVC_Desenv")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }

 }}
```

Configurei a web config:

```
    <connectionString>
<add name="EstudandoMVC_Desenv" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\OneDrive\Projetos ASP NET\COPEL\WillianRibeiro.EstudandoMVC\WillianRibeiro.EstudandoMVC.Web\App_Data\EstudandoMVC_BD.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

O problema ocorre quando vou adicionar a controller "Usuario" estou tentando adicionar a controller MVC 5 com as views e utilizando o Entity Framework. Faço toda a configuração e quando mando criar da o erro: 
"Erro ao executar o gerador de código selecionado: Uma exceção foi acionada pelo destino de uma chamada".

Já revi varias vezes o código e não consigo resolver.

Comment: Qual é a InnerException?

Answer (score 0):

Em startup.cs:

```
`public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = Configuration["ConexaoMySql:MySqlConnectionString"];
            services.AddDbContext<---SeuContexto--->(options =>
                options.UseMySql(connection)
            );
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }`
```

Answer (score -1):

Voce precisa criar uma Class contexto e a Class Usuario(que é referente a sua Tabela),ficaria mais o menos assim:

Essa é a class Contexto ,aonde vai fazer referencia a suas tabelas

```
public partial class EstudandoMVCContext: DbContext
{
    public EstudandoMVCContext()
        : base("name=EstudandoMVC_Desenv")//Refere ao nome da sua conexão
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
            .Property(e => e.nomeUsuario)
            .IsUnicode(false);

    }
}
```

E aqui vai ser a sua class Usuario(representando a sua tabela)

```
[Table("Usuario")]
public partial class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int idUsario { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string nomeUsuario { get; set; }
}
```

Se você já tiver as tabelas feitas no banco ,é mais fácil deixa o próprio  Entity Framework gerar essas class.

Answer (score -1):

Fazendo uma conexão no Visual Studio 2017 - ASP NET MVC - MySQL 5.5
estava tendo o mesmo problema relatado pelo colega.

Erro ao criar Controller:

> "Erro ao executar o gerador de código selecionado: Uma exceção foi
>   acionada pelo destino de uma chamada"

Seguindo as orientações acima ajustando o "Context", consegui resolver o problema.

Obrigado.